# Neptune query behavior during edge creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

Gremlin query submitted to neptune to create edge , behaves differently when source/target vertices are missing.

we are using gremlin query in below format to submit edge creation on amazon neptune.

````
    g.V('unq://id1').as('from')
    .addE('id1\~core.DataFlow').from('from')
    .to(\_\_.V('unq://id2'))
    .property('prop1','abcd')
    .property('prop2','xyz')```


The above query fails only when the target vertex which is unq://id2 is missing. With the exception 'The traversal has tried to use a null or non-existent value in the step'
It doesn't fail when the source vertex is missing. It also doesn't fail, when both the source & target vertex are missing.

Is this behavior expected?

I wanted my queries to fail when either vertices are missing.
````

Answer (score 0):

If the source vertex does not exist, the way the query is written, it will just end as the first V will not have yielded a result.

so if we assume that `'unq://id1'` does not exist, then the query will end after the `g.V('unq://id1')` part.

If you need to know that that vertex exists or otherwise fail you could use a `coalesce` step something like `.fold().coalesce(unfold(),fail('source vertex does not exist'))` after the initial `g.V(...)`.

As an alternative you could explore using the fairly new `mergeE` step. That step will return an error if either the source or target, or both, are missing.